# TSQL update trigger: joining inserted and deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have an on update trigger in SQL Server 2008. I only need to perform the trigger action if certain columns have been modified. Thus I'd like to check what has changed.

T-SQL offers an "if update( columnName )" construct. However, if many rows have been updated and only a single one of them has the particular column value changed "if update()" will have to return true. This'll make me perform the trigger action for far more rows than required.

So instead of using "if update()" I thought I'd just join the virtual deleted and inserted tables (the rows before and after update) and compare the relevant columns myself. However, how can I join the two tables? I cannot use the table's primary key since that may have been modified by the update. The only thing I can think of is joining by row_number(), i.e. implicit table ordering. This feels very wrong though and I don't know whether SQL Server actually offers any guarantuees that rows in inserted are ordered the same as in deleted.

Comment: never change a primary key.  if you need to change the values of the primary key, then you should use a surrogate primary key, like an identity.

Comment: Why do foreign key constraints allow "on update cascade/set null" if "never change a primary key" is such an iron rule? If a primary key consists of something that has meaning in the real world it may well change at some point. I do try to avoid it where possible and my own schemata have non-mutable primary keys, however I don't see it as an absolute taboo? And in this particular case the schema design isn't under my control anyways, so I can't do anything about it.

Comment: Foreign keys may refer to unique constraints, not only to PK. This invalidates your argument aobut CASCADE

Comment: in a very simple system you could get by with updating PKs.  However, when you move into very large systems with hundreds of tables it becomes problematic.  Jane Doe gets married and becomes Jane Smith.  In most tables we keep the last change user info.  How would you cascade this change across several hundred tables, with possibly millions of rows affected?  Also, hopefully your primary key will not be part of a html link (in an e-mail or bookmark) that will break after your update, or worse open the wrong data.  Will you cascade that PK update to all of your activity log tables?

Comment: I agree. And as already mentioned my own schema designs adhere to the non-changing primary key rule. Which leads to another question: Can you enforce this somehow? I.e. make primary keys immutable? I could imagine instead of update triggers doing the trick. Is there an easier method?

Comment: @KM I know this is a super old thread, but while that's good advice, I'm reminded of the quote apocryphally attributed to Albert Einstein. "In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they are not". It's sound advice, but we live in an imperfect world and updates to primary keys happen in many many environments.

Comment: @Xedi, I seen a lot of crap designs and code, and I'd put the update of primary keys in the pile with the crap designs every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your design (that allows changing primary keys) it seems very hard to build a consistent logic.

Say, you have this table:

```
id   value
1    2
2    1
```

and issue this operation:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     id = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
        value = CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

which updates both records but leaves the table as this:

```
id   value
2    1
1    2
```

, which from relational point of view is similar to not changing the table at all.

The whole point of the primary keys is that they never change.

Comment: Agreed. But how do you disallow modifications of the primary key? In general?  
It won't be an option for me in any case since the table design is not under my control. See my commments to devio's answer.

Comment: @BuschnicK: use `IF UPDATE()`, as in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use IDENTITY columns as Primary Keys, you don't have the problem of updated PK columns.

Comment: The primary key consists of more than a single column. I like to avoid identity keys (see Joe Celko for some arguments for this). And the table schema isn't under my control anyways. That's the whole point for the triggers - propagate changes to the original table to our own.

Comment: So you can modify triggers on the table you don't control, but not the schema itself?  Can you possibly construct a new table with immutable primary keys and expose a properly-named view of it in place of the original table?  That would allow you to have a fixed ID that you could track in the triggers.

Comment: The tables live on my db server and I'm admin, so in that sense I can do whatever I want with them. However, they "belong" to a commercial ERP system which would break if I changed the table layout or behaviour significantly.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent a PK from changing, add this to the top of your trigger:

```
IF (UPDATE(yourPKcol1) OR UPDATE(yourPKcol2))
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('Primary Key change not permitted!',16,1) 
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to (as I mentioned in a comment above) create a new table, if possible, that includes all the data in the original but also includes an immutable primary key (IDENTITY works, or you can use something else if you prefer).  You can then expose a view of this new table that mimics the name and schema of the original table.  This will give you a fixed ID that you can use to track changes as you wish.

All this assumes that a view works adequately in your particular case -- if the app is doing something very weird it might not work properly, but if it's just throwing standard CRUD-style SQL at it it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your trade off is simplicity & maintainability vs performance
if performance is not prioritized use if update(YourTriggerActionColumn) directly
if performance is prioritized then the way to do it is use "if update(PrimaryKeyColumn)" so if primary key didn't change use inserted-deleted join else if the primary key did changed then check "if update(YourTriggerActionColumn)"
since PKs don't often change then most of the time the inserted-deleted join method will be used thus solves your performance problem.
little late but just my 2 cents :)